# Matlab/OpenCV stereo vision distance measurement is not accurate

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

After stereo calibration, when I run the Matlab example for stereo depth estimation (SDE), the distances are wrong:  at about 2 meters, it always reports distance as less than 1m.
And my 3D scene reconstruction looks cone-shaped instead of like the real scene.
Disparity map is very noisy (non-smooth), but resembles the scene.

If I 'feed' the SDE script the example file instead of webcam input, it runs okay, all looks great; when I feed it from two webcams ( 'Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920' ) that's when I get the above bad results, beginning with rough disparity map.

I've tried many different calibration attempts with just a few images up to about 60, with Matlab's checkerboard pattern at different angles (never > 45) and distance to cameras about 8 to 20'.  Camera lenses are 3.8175" apart always, and are mounted to top edge of laptop.  Followed Matlab's recommended workflow.

What am I doing wrong in calibration?

Matlab R2015a.
Laptop Windows 7 64-bit
Checkerboard pattern is 37" x 27"

............JUST DISCOVERED PROBLEM:
Was creating disparity map with this:
disparityMap = disparity(frameLeftGray, frameRightGray);
However, my camera #1 is on the right, and Matlab says default disparity range is [0 64] and for cam #1 right it should be [-128 0], but that changes the disparity map to all uniform blue.

Comment: do you have any estimation of the focal lens of the cameras you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.  (1) left/right of calibration and images and detection data structures must match.  (2) Use mm for checkboard square size.  Inches causes malfunction, because all else is in mm.